# Python - calling on method in Point to check if Point is in Rectangle

Tags: python, class, methods, rectangles

I'm learning classes and methods in Python and I'm doing the Rectangle/Point exercise in 'How to Think Like a Computer Scientist'. I've researched, but have not come across someone the same problem that I'm running into.
I'm having a problem calling on self.width and self.height in my Rectangle Class.  What's strange is that I have no problem calling on it in my other methods that I wrote.  When I debug, it shows the instance of my width and height as nothing and now I'm at my last resort - here!

Here is the code I'm using:

```
class Point:
    """Sets up a class point. If user doesn't supply args it starts at
     0,0)"""
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Rectangle:
    '''A class to create rectangle objects '''

    def __init__(self, posn, w, h):
        self.corner = posn  '''position of rectangle as tuple (Point Class)'''
        self.width = w      '''Sets self.width as w'''
        self.height = h     '''Sets self.height as h'''

    '''Added grow and move methods to display how I'm calling
    self.width/height and self.corner.x/y. These both work when I call them'''

    def grow(self, delta_width, delta_height):
        '''Grow or shrink object by deltas'''
        self.width += delta_width
        self.height += delta_height

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        '''Move this object by the deltas'''
        self.corner.x += dx
        self.corner.y += dy

    '''This is where I'm having the problem. '''
    def contains(self, posn):
        return (self.width > self.corner.x >= 0
        and self.height > self.corner.y >= 0)

r = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), 10, 5)

print(r.contains(Point(0,0))) '''Should return True'''
print(r.contains(Point(3,3))) '''Should return True'''
print(r.contains(Point(3, 7))) '''Should return False, but returns True'''
```

Comment: In your `contains` method, you aren't actually using the `posn` argument. You need to test `posn` against the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: @JETM `a > a >= a` is valid in Python but mostly is not in other languages.

Comment: @DKrueger Am I not passing it as the class Point(3,3) to the rectangle 'r'?  So the Point I am passing when calling it in print(r.contains(Point(3,3))) is (3,3) and the size of the rectangle is domain [0 10), and range is [0, 5) in my original rectangle r = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), 10, 5)?

Comment: @ChrisAvina Yes, you are passing it in, but you never use it in the method. Nowhere in the method is the location of `posn` actually used. Maybe instead of `self.corner.x`, you meant to use `posn.x` (and the same for `y`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, posn, w, h):
        self.corner = posn
        self.width = w
        self.height = h


    def contains(self, point):
        return self.width > point.x >= self.corner.x and self.height > point.y >= self.corner.y
```

What the `contains` method is doing is:

1) Checking if the given point's x position is less than the rectangle's width and larger than or equal to the rectangle's corner's x position:

```
self.width > point.x >= self.corner.x
```

2) And then doing the same thing for y and the height:

```
self.height > point.y >= self.corner.y
```

3) Put together it looks like:

```
def contains(self, point):
    return self.width > point.x >= self.corner.x and self.height > point.y >= self.corner.y
```